# Ошибка при компиляции библиотеки boost

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь из библиотеки boost использовать float128.
Подключаю так:

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/float128.hpp>
namespace mp = boost::multiprecision;
mp::float128 N = 0;
```

Выдает ошибку:  #error:  "Sorry compiler is neither GCC, not Intel, don't know how to configure this header."
В чем ошибка?Или подскажите какой тип данных из этой библиотеки можно использовать для работы с большим числом с плавающей точкой.

**Update**

Как взаимодействовать теперь целый тип из boost c float? Получается так:
Подключаю библиотеку:

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_bin_float.hpp>
namespace mp = boost::multiprecision;
mp::cpp_bin_float_quad N = 1010.5;
mp::cpp_int a=5;
```

Теперь когда я это число пытаюсь поделить на целое большое число из этой библиотеки:

```
N/=5;
```

выдает ошибку:отсутствует оператор "/=", соответствующий этим операндам.
Как можно одновременно использовать два этих типа?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как говорит [документация Boost'а](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/floats/float128.html):

> The float128 number type is a very thin wrapper around GCC's float128 or Intel's _Quad data types and provides an real-number type that is a drop-in replacement for the native C++ floating-point types, but with a 113 bit mantissa, and compatible with FORTRAN's 128-bit QUAD real.

Т.е. это всего лишь обёртка на типом [`float128`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Floating-Types.html) из gcc. Использовать его с другими компиляторами не получится. О чём и говорится в ошибке.

Реализация в хедерах двоичной плавающей арифметики с произвольной точностью от boost'а называется [cpp_bin_float](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/floats/cpp_bin_float.html). По факту это единственный FP-backend за пределами GNU мира. Относительно медленный, зато без зависимостей.

Аналогом непосредственно `float128` является тип `cpp_bin_float_quad`.

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_bin_float.hpp>
using namespace boost::multiprecision;
cpp_bin_float_quad N = 0;
```

**Update**

Для того чтобы использовать разные типы из библиотек произвольной точности boost'а в одном выражении их необходимо явно приводить к одному одним из [способов](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/conversions.html), например с помощью шаблона `convert_to<>()`:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_bin_float.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

using namespace boost::multiprecision;
int main(void) {
    cpp_bin_float_quad fpN = 1;
    cpp_int iN = 5;
    cpp_bin_float_quad fp2;

    fpN /= iN.convert_to<cpp_bin_float_quad>();
    std::cout << fpN;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: появились новые проблемы, посмотрите, пожалуйста, тему обновил.

Comment: @Александр, не cтоит менять часть вопроса, на которую уже дан ответ... Стоит либо задать новый вопрос с перекрёсными ссылками на текущий, либо добавить уточнение ниже основного вопроса явно обозначив его как таковое (например подзаголовком `**Update**`).

Comment: спасибо, исправил замечание.